# MOSS web service to find out if a user has access to a document library

Tags: sharepoint

Is there any MOSS out of the box web service which allows us to check if a user has access to a document library if I know the URL for the document library. I have the URL for the SharePoint document library, user name and password.

Thanks.

Yes, please if a user has "Read" permission on document library. If there is no out of the box web service, and we develop our own web service, does this need to be deployed on a server where MOSS is insalled?

Comment: Just to clarify; the service would determine if a user has the "Read" permission level on the Library?

Comment: Also, there is no out of the box solution for this, but it is relatively easy to roll your own web service that takes the username as an input; and returns a true/false result.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing OOB with MOSS 2007/ WSS 3.0
Check out [SharePoint Sushi](http://sushi.codeplex.com/)
for a useful library that may help you either as a starting point or as a component in your final solution.